# Постинг сообщений VK картинка + ссылка

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Доброй ночи.
Написал постер сообщений в свою группу ВК, но появилась проблема.
При формировании запроса с wall.post в поле attachments передаю ссылку на товар и имя фотки, так вот по какой то причине ВК принимает только первый параметр. Например если ставлю первой ссылку, то пост появляется со ссылкой но без фото и наоборот.

Есть какие либо мысли на эту тему?

```
$url = 'http://88.myjino.ru/arn/tovar.php?id='.$id_tovar;
$photo = 'photo19066251_'.$save_photo['response'][0]['id'];
//Публикуем пост с фото
$request_param = [
    'owner_id' => '-'.$id_group,
    'friends_only' => 0,
    'from_group' => 1,
    'message' => $message,
    'access_token' => 'e16e2d26345549cfd532118146fd6a08ded13e723eb7d99be9279ac86d52536fafe2a7ced8e4139e4afda',
    'v' => '5.92',
    'attachments' => $url,$photo
    ];
//print_r($request_param);
//echo $save_photo['response'][0]['id'];
$post = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post?'. http_build_query($request_param)), true);
```

P.S. Токен не действующий:)

Comment: Вы же знаете, что элементы в массиве разделяются запятой? Вот после `$url` у вас стоит запятая, и `$photo` после запятой уже никаким боком не относится к `'attachments'`. Соберите единую нормальную строку в attachments

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду $url.','.$photo ?

Comment: Благодарю) Все работает, как написал выше.